# Dynamic Columns - Fields using linq to sql

Tags: c#

I am using Linq to Sql and I need to fetch only the needed fields. This is something that I was able to accomplish using Dynamic Linq. Does anyone know how I can fetch only one or more fields and then add it to my Grid without re query and regenerate the whole object again?? Something similar to Merge method of a dataset but with Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question. Does one of these help you?

```
var List1 = db.myTable.Select(k => new myObject
  {
    ID = k.Id,
    field1 = k.field1
  });

var List2 = from k in db.myTable select new myObject()
  {
      ID = k.Id,
      field1 = k.field1
  };
```

else can you provide an example?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To give a real scenario: A user perform a search on a table (Entity) lets say Customers. For performance we select only 3 basic fields (ID,Name,Address). We want to provide a menu for the user to be able to add more fields but (for performance again) we only want to fetch the new field selected by the used not to re-query and add the new field/or fields. In a older version we did that with the use of vTable which is an in memory fast datasource and has capabilities like AddColumn and Merge. I hope this helps in understanding my problem.